# RValue Reference behaviour

Tags: c++

I have been trying to understand what happens behind the move constructor scene but something is missing in my mind.

```
   struct A {
     int s;
     A() : s(10) {}
     A(const A& o) : s(o.s) { std::cout << "copy contructor" << std::endl;}
     A(A&& o) : s(std::move(o.s)) {std::cout <<"move constructor" << std::endl;}
   };

   struct B  {
     std::string  s;
     B() : s("max") {;}
     B(const B& o) : s(o.s) {std::cout <<"copy contructor" << std::endl;}
     B(B&& o) : s(std::move(o.s)) {std::cout <<"move contructor" << std::endl;}
   };

   int main() {

   A a1;
   std::cout << " Before move " << " " << a1.s << std::endl;
   A a2 = std::move(a1); 
   std::cout << " After move" << " "  << a1.s << std::endl;

   B b1;
   std::cout << " Before move"  << " " << b1.s << std::endl;
   B b2 = std::move(b1);
   std::cout << " After move" << " "<< b1.s << std::endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

calling std::move on an object, should make clear that although the object will still be around after the move, we're happy to empty".

```
The output is 
Before move 10  
move constructor
After move 10

Before move max
move constructor
After move ""
```

I have two questions:

1) Move constructor of struct B "steals" the resource and leave b1.s empty (""). It makes perfectly sense to me, why this is not happening with a1.s. It looks a copy and not a move.

2) If I remove std::move from a move constructor of struct B,

```
 B(B&& o) : s(o.s) {std::cout <<"move contructor" << std::endl;}
```

I guess a copy constructor should be invoked. Now the output is:

```
Before move max
move constructor
After move max
```

It makes partially sense to me. I understand completely "Resource after move max". Now it looks a copy but there is no trace of "copy constructor" that should be printed out with copy constructor call.

Definitely something is missing in my mind, might someone explain why ? 
Thx

Answer (score 3):

1. Moving from a primitive type is exactly the same as a copy. Moving is only really significant when you're dealing with objects that contain dynamically allocated resources. For example, a `std::string` will dynamically allocate its string contents, which are being moved from the original `std::string` to the new one.
2. The move constructor is still chosen because of the `std::move` here:

   ```
   B b2 = std::move(b1);
   ```

   The expression `std::move(b1)` is an rvalue, so the move constructor will be chosen to construct `b2`. Changing what the move constructor does won't change this. What you *have* changed is that the move constructor behaves the same as a copy constructor (except for the fact it prints "Using a move constructor"). Because you've changed `s(std::move(o.s))` to `s(o.s)`, the internal string will just be copied over.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this point is also quite blurry. So I tried to decompose a step further according to what I understood in the following case : the almighty swap on rvalue references, for a class holding a resource (an int*)

So this is the aim (I discarded most formatting you'll see in the trace...)

```
int main() {
    int a {1}; cout << "a:" << a << "_@_" << (&a) << "\n";
    int b {2}; cout << "b:" << b << "_@_" << (&b) << "\n";
    C ca {"ca",&a}; C cb {"cb",&b};
    ca.p();cb.p();
    swap(ca,cb);
    ca.p();cb.p();
}
```

Now the swap using rvalue references is the "classic"

```
void swap(C& a, C& b){
    C tmp {"tmp",static_cast<C&&>(a)}; 
    a = static_cast<C&&>(b);
    b = static_cast<C&&>(tmp);
}
```

So, this is my understanding of how the class should look like

```
class C{
  private : string _id; int* _pi;

  public:

    //default construct
    C(string id):              
    _id(id), _pi(nullptr)            
    { cout << _id << ":C()_default_build\n"; }

    //construct from int
    C(string id, int* pi):     
    _id(id), _pi(new int(*pi))       
    { cout << _id << ":C(" << (*_pi) << "_@_" << _pi << ")_build_from_int\n"; }

    //contruct from other object, by copy
    C(string id, const C& other):
    _id(id), _pi(new int(*(other._pi)))  
    { cout << _id << ":C(" << (*_pi) << "_@_" << _pi << ")_build_as_copy_from(" <<    other._id << ")\n"; }

    //contruct from other object, by move    
    C(string id, C&& other):       
    _id(id), _pi( other._pi )  
    { 
        other._pi = nullptr;
        cout << _id << ":C(" << (*_pi) << "_@_" << _pi << ")_build_by_move_from(" << other._id << ")\n"; 
    }


    //destructor
    ~C() {
        cout << "~~ destroy " << _id;
        if (_pi){
            cout << " holding " << (*_pi) << " at " << _pi ;
            delete _pi; _pi = nullptr;
        }
        else
            cout << " __empty__ ";
        cout << " ~~\n";
    }

    //move assignment
    C& operator=(C&& other) noexcept{ 
        if (this != &other) {
            _pi = other._pi;
        other._pi = nullptr;
            cout << "## " << _id << " steals " << _pi << " from " << other._id << " ##\n";
        }
        return *this;
    }

    //display
    void p() { 
        cout << ">> " << _id;
        if (_pi)
            cout << " points to " << (*_pi) << " at " << _pi; 
        else
            cout << "__empty__";
        cout << " <<\n";
    }

};
```

So now, fire ! ... The trace

```
/**trace

--- simulate rvalue references ---

a:1_@_0x7ffd6a1af45c
b:2_@_0x7ffd6a1af458

ca:C(1_@_0x558eabb0c280)_build_from_int
cb:C(2_@_0x558eabb0c2a0)_build_from_int

>> ca points to 1 at 0x558eabb0c280 <<
>> cb points to 2 at 0x558eabb0c2a0 <<

tmp:C(1_@_0x558eabb0c280)_build_by_move_from(ca)
## ca steals 0x558eabb0c2a0 from cb ##
## cb steals 0x558eabb0c280 from tmp ##
~~ destroy tmp __empty__  ~~

>> ca points to 2 at 0x558eabb0c2a0 <<
>> cb points to 1 at 0x558eabb0c280 <<

~~ destroy cb holding 1 at 0x558eabb0c280 ~~
~~ destroy ca holding 2 at 0x558eabb0c2a0 ~~

*/
```

OK.. for this example, it works... Is that a correct answer ?